# Problems with jQuery if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I am trying to create a simple if statement: if `.information-overlay` has the CSS property `display:block`, add `background-color:blue;`; to `body`. If not, don't.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="information">Information</div>
<div class="work">Work</div>
<div class="information-overlay">INFORMATION OVERLAY</div>
<div class="work-overlay">WORK OVERLAY</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.information-overlay, .work-overlay {
    display:none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: salmon;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.information').click(function () {
    $('.information-overlay').fadeToggle();
    $('.work-overlay').fadeOut();
    if ($('.information-overlay').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('body').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
    }
    if ($('.information-overlay').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('body').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
    }
});
```

This works fine, however it does **not** set the `body` back to `background-color: white;` when the `toggle` fades out (or is call the second `if` again). It is stuck on blue. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is a JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/hWXeM/6/

Comment: You need to check it in the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass action to be performed once the animation is complete

```
$('.information').click(function () {
    $('.information-overlay').fadeToggle(function () {
        if ($('.information-overlay').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('body').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
        }
        if ($('.information-overlay').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('body').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
        }
    });
    $('.work-overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hWXeM/7/

Answer (score 2):

Instead add the `if..else..` statement inside the `fadeToggle` like this

```
$('.information-overlay').fadeToggle( function() {
        if ($('.information-overlay').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('body').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
    } else if ($('.information-overlay').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('body').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
    }
    });
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hWXeM/8/)